# Connecting LED strips lights under outdoor stairs

Tags: led

Hey guys I'm looking to install LED strips lights underneath the  tread of our outdoor garden stairs. I have 5 rows of stairs and each row is 1.5wide. I will need to install 5x 1.5m led strip's under each tread. My question is what's the best way to connect these strips to a power supply, in series? Or run dedicated wires to each strip and connect multiple led strip's to one power supply? Is that even possible? 12v or 24v and I'd like to have a PIR as well. Thanks in advance for any solid advice to this complete novice!

Comment: Welcome @BNAK, yes everything you have mentioned above is possible, the Voltage will depend on the type of LED strip you plan on using. The way to wire them up (Parallel 1.5m Strips vs Series 1.5 Strips) will depend on the strips & the power supply. You need to suggest what strips you want to use, LED density, number of diodes (RGB/RBGW/W) before we can help further. To me it sounds like you want something like a waterproof version of this https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32950789769.html

Comment: it makes no difference how you connect the strips together because the LEDs are all connected in parallel

Comment: @jsotola no it does. Running power through the strips to wire then another strip will introduce high resistance due to the FPC and voltage drops. Wiring in parallel would reduce that.

Comment: I would say learn a little bit of DC electronics.  That will make this job a whole lot easier because you'll have the vocabulary to understand what to do and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In parallel.  if you connect them in series, the last one in the string will be a lot dimmer than the first.  It's up to you whether to use fat cables running from string to string, or separate thinner wires to each.

Get an appropriate LED supply for the number of strings you're using.

You can buy standalone PIR units.  Connect your power supply to one of those.

Comment: I think if you connect them in series the shorter strips will be brighter and might even burn out.